# Trying to upload a file using goftp library gives a "502 RFC 2228 authentication not implemented." error

Tags: go, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to a server using FTP (using [goftp](https://github.com/dutchcoders/goftp) library). Here is my current code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "github.com/dutchcoders/goftp"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "path/filepath"
    "os"
)

var client *goftp.FTP

func main() {
    // connect to FTP
    client, err := goftp.ConnectDbg("192.168.206.226:21")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    config := tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        ClientAuth:         tls.RequestClientCert,
    }

    if err = client.AuthTLS(&config); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if err := client.Login("aaa", "bbbb"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // upload new S10 file using FTP
    err = filepath.Walk("c:\\Temp", upload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func upload(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if strings.Compare(f.Name(), "S10") == 0 {
        path := strings.TrimSuffix(path, f.Name())

        var file *os.File
        if file, err = os.Open(path); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        defer file.Close()
        if err := client.Stor("/sd1/myFile", file); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I followed the code available on [goftp](https://github.com/dutchcoders/goftp) github page, but it is not working for me. I always get this error:

```
go : 2018/05/09 10:23:28 < 220 192.168.206.226 FTP server (QNXNTO-ftpd 20081216) ready.
At line:1 char:1
+ go run main.go
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (2018/05/09 10:2...0081216) ready.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

2018/05/09 10:23:28 220 192.168.206.226 FTP server (QNXNTO-ftpd 20081216) ready.
2018/05/09 10:23:28 > AUTH TLS
502 RFC 2228 authentication not implemented.

2018/05/09 10:23:28 < 502 RFC 2228 authentication not implemented.
exit status 1
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Can't seem to understand what the issue is.

Comment: Take a debugger and debug your code perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FTP server does not support TLS/SSL encryption. So you cannot use it.

Remove the `AuthTLS` call.